# pip command not found in virtual env even if file is there

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

These are the steps I did:

1. Created a virtual env using `python3 -m venv myvenv`
2. Activate the virtual env using `myvenv/bin/activate`
3. Run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, to upgrade pip.
4. run `pip install -r requirements.txt`
5. It throws an error: `bash: /Users/vince/Django Projects/test/myvenv/bin/pip: "/Users/vince/Django: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

When I tried using pip2 install, it works, why is that so?

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Can you clarify step 2? On linux / mac you need to run ’source env/bin/activate’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/Users/vince/Django Projects/test/myvenv/bin/pip` starts with [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) `/Users/vince/Django Projects/test/myvenv/bin/python` (look it up). The problem is the path contains a space in its name and shebangs are not allowed to have spaces.

Remove the virtualenv, it's unusable. Recreate it under a path that doesn't have spaces and other fancy characters.

*Upd*. You can run scripts manually:

```
"/Users/vince/Django Projects/test/myvenv/bin/python" "/Users/vince/Django Projects/test/myvenv/bin/pip"
```

But that's painful.

Comment: With test, on Mac it's OK with space in `venv` path, but on Ubuntu, it raise `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: On any Unix it always be an error. It seems Mac OS X is not exactly a Unix.

Comment: I think Mac just have handled this case. Without space path, the `shebang` line is `#!/Users/fogmoon/temp/test/env/bin/python`, while with space path is `#!/bin/sh`, then following `'''exec' "/Users/fogmoon/temp/test/aaa bbb/env/bin/python" "$0" "$@" ' '''`. But in Ubuntu,  the `shebang` line is alwasys `#!"/home/fogmoon/temp/test/aaa bbb/myvenv/bin/python"`.